# How can i optimise code for update mysql tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Well i have this code:

```
<?php
require_once('../assets/db/DBConnect.php');
$conn = DBConnect::conn();

echo "<pre>";
$usersWithoutSurnames = [];
$usersWithSurnames = [];
$i = 0;

$query = 'SELECT * FROM person where surName IS NULL';
$res = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($i > 7)
        break;
    $usersWithoutSurnames[] = $row;
    $i++;
}

foreach ($usersWithoutSurnames as $user) {
    $getSurnameQuery = 'SELECT clientSecondname from policy WHERE clientEGN = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';

    if($stmt = $conn->prepare($getSurnameQuery)) {
        $egn = $user['egn'];
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $egn);

        $r = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($clientSecondname);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $user['surName'] = $clientSecondname;
        $usersWithSurnames[] = $user;
        $stmt->close();
    }
}

var_dump($usersWithoutSurnames);
echo '-------------------------------------------------';
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($usersWithSurnames); exit;
```

The idea: There is a table with `users (person)` but some users doesn't have surnames, so i check another `table (policy)` for their surnames, and fill second array with same users but with surnames, after that i will fill and table with this array. You can see i get only 7 users, cuz when i try to get more users it timeout, can i optimise this code/queries to work with more users?

Tables structure:

**person:**

```
|------------------------------------------------
|  Id  | firstName | secondName | lastName | EGN
|   1  | test      |   NULL     |  test    | 123
|   2  | test      |   NULL     |  test    | 321
```

**policy:**

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Id  | clientFirstname | clientSecondname | clientLastname | clientEGN
|   1  | test            |   test           |  test          |  123
|   2  | test            |   test           |  test          |  321
```

Comment: Can you add the structure of your person and policy tables? It seems like you could just join between the two tables in a single query.

Comment: @Raptord it's edit!

Comment: Why timeout on such simple query? How much size of your table?

Comment: person is 815 000 rows, policy is 678 000 rows.

Comment: add index to columns in tables to speed up the operation.

Answer (score 2):

janmyszkier raises a good point, in that it seems like your tables are missing keys and/or indexes. These simple queries should not be crippling your system.

As for optimizing your current SQL, you can combine your two select statements into a single one by joining the two tables:

```
select 
  person.*,
  policy.clientSecondname
from person
left join policy on policy.clientEGN = person.EGN
where person.secondName is null
```

Make sure you have indexes on the EGN and clientEGN columns to speed up the join.

Note that your code example refers to a column named "surName", but that column doesn't exist in the table definition your provided. I used secondName instead since it seemed like the best match.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure the tables have indices (if there are none for `clientEGN` add one with ADD INDEX). this should speed up your search queries "a bit"

once you add the index, please let us now if your code still requires optimizations.
The code is not optimal, but easy to understand and maintain. I could suggest doing a JOIN and UPDATE joined with IF within, but that would make the code more complex and problematic for junior dev to maintain, so at this point, I won't advice changing what you currently have.